# Examples using LIATE rule for Integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

Popular textbook contain many examples of integrals which can be computed by parts using the LIATE Rule. However there is almost no example of the case LI, that is a logarithmic function times an inverse trigonometric one and computed by parts. Can you provide some references to textbooks or websites where one can find such examples which can be proposed to high-school student which are learning IPP the first time? 
    (Please, no gamma function, beta function, Riemann zeta function, dilogarithm, digamma function, Dirichlet eta function, no contour integration.)
    Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\arcsin(x)\ln(x)$ has an elementary antiderivative.  I don't have a sourcebook, though.

Comment: Nothing general here, for example log times arctan does not have an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: Today I did find In an old book by W.L.FERRAR integral Calculs Oxford Univ Press 1958, p. 19 the following example: tan^-1(x)log(1+x^2). As Hint it is suggested u= tan^-1(x)log(1+x^2) and dv=dx. (Reported here for reference)